# No me cargar los objetos a mi ArrayList

Tags: java, android-studio

Me encuentro con la problemática de que mi programa no esta cargando los objetos a la ArrayList. Cuando intento agregar la lista a listView no aparece nada, haciendo un Log.d("Largo de la Lista, largoLista) me devuelve 0 en la consola, es decir la lista esta vacía. Les dejo el codigo completo para ver si pueden descubirir en donde me estoy equivocando

```
public class RealizarReserva extends AppCompatActivity {

FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
ArrayAdapter<Vuelo> mAdapter;
ArrayList<Vuelo> listaVuelos = new ArrayList();
ListView miListaVuelos;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_realizar_reserva);
    this.setTitle("Realizar Reserva");

    miListaVuelos = findViewById(R.id.listadoVuelos);



    db.collection("vuelos")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                            Vuelo v = new Vuelo(document.getString("numero"),document.getString("cupo_primera_clase"),document.getString("cupo_clase_turista"),document.getString("fecha_salida"),document.getString("hora_salida"));
                            listaVuelos.add(v);
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Error al traer los vuelos.", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Vuelo>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaVuelos);
    miListaVuelos.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    String largolista = String.valueOf(listaVuelos.size());
    Log.d("Tamaño de la Lista",largolista);

}
```

Les dejo la clase vuelo por si les hace falta, los datos los trae de una base de datos en firestore. No entiendo en que me estoy equivocando.

```
public class Vuelo {
private String numero_vuelo;
private String cupo_primera;
private String cupo_turista;
private String fecha_salida;
private String hora_salida;

public Vuelo(String nro, String cp, String ct, String fs, String hs)
{
    this.numero_vuelo=nro;
    this.cupo_primera=cp;
    this.cupo_turista=ct;
    this.fecha_salida=fs;
    this.hora_salida=hs;
}

public String getNumero_vuelo() {
    return numero_vuelo;
}

public void setNumero_vuelo(String numero_vuelo) {
    this.numero_vuelo = numero_vuelo;
}

public String getCupo_primera() {
    return cupo_primera;
}

public void setCupo_primera(String cupo_primera) {
    this.cupo_primera = cupo_primera;
}

public String getCupo_turista() {
    return cupo_turista;
}

public void setCupo_turista(String cupo_turista) {
    this.cupo_turista = cupo_turista;
}

public String getFecha_salida() {
    return fecha_salida;
}

public void setFecha_salida(String fecha_salida) {
    this.fecha_salida = fecha_salida;
}

public String getHora_salida() {
    return hora_salida;
}

public void setHora_salida(String hora_salida) {
    this.hora_salida = hora_salida;
}
```

}

Muchas Gracias